# how to enable sand box murchant account reference transaction from paypal

Tags: java, paypal, payment-gateway

i have paypal account and sandbox account

whent doing express  checkout  in java i got following error

> Merchant not enabled for reference transactions

how to enable reference transaction on murchant sandbox testaccount ?

**anils_1353572220_biz@gmail.com** this is my seller/murchant testaccount.

what is the process to enable that reference transacion

=======**=please enable or  better to send approch i will do on my own**=================

Answer (score 2):

You need to request that PayPal techs enable this for you.  You can do so by submitting a thread at the [PayPal developer sandbox forum](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/paypal-sandbox) or submitting a ticket at [PayPal MTS](http://www.paypal.com/mts).  I would probably do both.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly their doc is very unclear. To enable reference transactions for a sandbox account:

1. Go to http://developer.paypal.com/ -> [Sandbox Accounts](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts)
2. [Create](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/accounts/create) a Business Account
3. Send the Email Id used to create the account to the [Merchant Technical Support](http://www.paypal.com/mts).

Reference: https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/940

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still looking for answers here:

**PayPal account:**

**Sandbox:**

- Reference Transactions are automatically enabled on Sandbox accounts created after December 15, 2015.
- If your Sandbox account was created before this date, contact PayPal's Customer Service and ask to have Reference Transactions enabled on your Sandbox account.

**Live/Production:**

- PayPal must approve enablement of Reference Transactions for your Live account.
- To request approval for your Live account, contact PayPal's Customer Service.

source: https://www.paypal.com/ph/smarthelp/article/how-do-i-use-checkout-with-reference-transactions-and-payflow-pro-ts1503